# Can I use an if statement within a for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to use an if statement inside a for loop to check if my value is greater than 0 and then execute my code.I’m not sure how to go about this, this is what I have currently.

**searchResults[‘results’][searchResult][‘location’]** is an int

```
for (searchResult in searchResults[‘results’]) {
  var resultLocationLabel = “”;
  const locationsHolder = searchResults[‘results’][searchResult][‘location’].split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < locationsHolder.length; i++) {
    if(searchResults[‘results’][searchResult][‘location’] > 0){
    resultLocationLabel += “L”+locationsHolder[i].trim() + “ “;
    }

  }
}
```

The contents of searchResults[‘results’] when console logged shows (I haven’t put all the records as it is very long only two so you can see that there is an issue when two locations are attached to a place):

```
{id: “10045”, name: “Disneyland”, location: “1”}

{id: “5465”, name: “Six flags”, location: “2, 3”}
```

However this doesn’t work for when I have more than one location tag attached to a place. To further explain what I’m trying to do is I have a search bar which when the user enters a place a list of possible places come up however when I use this if statement when a place has more than one location the search results are displayed incorrectly.

```
L1 Disneyland 
Six flags 
L2 Thorpe Park
```

When it should look like this:

```
L1 Disneyland 
L2 L3 Six flags 
L2 Thorpe Park
```

So is it possible to even use an if statement within a for loop?

Comment: Please show aus the content of the searchresults['results']

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff okay I’ve done that hope that helps

Comment: yes you can use

Comment: @MohammedRabiullaRABI but my issue is that I’m not sure how to structure it so that it works as right now this if statement that I have causes issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes of course you can use `if` inside a loop

only problem i see (without the backtics) is this line:

```
if(searchResults[‘results’][searchResult][‘location’] > 0){
```

You probably want the value  "1, 2" to count as `2` therefore u could use split to cast an array from the string and then use `.length` to be able to compare

```
if(searchResults['results'][searchResult]['location'].split(',').length > 1){
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end you do not need the if at all.

```js
let searchResults = { results : [{ id : "10045", name: "Disneyland", location: "1"},
                            { id : "5465", name: "Six flags", location: "2, 3" }] };

for (searchResult in searchResults['results']) {
  var resultLocationLabel = "";
  const locationsHolder = searchResults['results'][searchResult]['location'].split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < locationsHolder.length; i++) {
    resultLocationLabel += "L"+locationsHolder[i].trim() + " ";
  }
   console.log(resultLocationLabel);
}
```